# Ao preencher o campo Data, executar uma ação do jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho um campo `data` e preciso que ao terminar de preencher a data... Executar uma função para listagem de um formulário SELECT.

```
<input id="dp1" class="input-small" onkeyup="mascaraData(this);" name="data"  type="date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy"  required="required">
```

Comment: sim e qual o problema da sua função mascaraData(this) ?

Comment: basta colocar o seu método do jquery aqui: `onkeyup="mascaraData(this);metodojQuery();"` ou fazer conforme a minha resposta abaixo.

Comment: Sim, gostaria que ao completar o preenchimento do campo, executasse uma nova função, que eu farei para listagem de clientes, por exemplo.

Comment: Porém para fazer a sua lista, primeiro preciso saber o que seria essa lista, concorda, e de onde você está retirando a sua lista.

Comment: Vou fazer um retorno Json, para listagem de clientes que está no banco de dados... O esquema seria o seguinte: SELECIONA DATA, SELECIONA O CLIENTE, QUE POR SUA VEZ LISTA AS CHAMADAS FEITAS PARA ESTE CLIENTE...

Comment: Faça uma saída com o seu `echo json_encode($array_dados)`.

Comment: e depois capture ela, conforme nesta minha resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77326/como-fazer-para-trazer-tabela-com-dados-ao-retornar-de-um-insert/77697#77697

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que o que você quer e que ao sair do campo data, o evento seja disparado. Para isso você pode utilizar o evento [.focusout](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/) que é disparado no exato momento que o seu elemento perde o foco.

Um exemplo:

```
$('#dp1').focusout(function(){
    //Coloque aqui o código que você precisa
});
```

Outro evento que pode ser utilizado é o [.blur](https://api.jquery.com/blur/), a diferença entre o .focusout e .blur é que o blur é disparado quando o elemento perde o foco, o .focusout é disparado quando o elemento, ou qualquer outro elemento que esteja dentro dele perde o foco.

Acredito que o .blur irá se aplicar melhor ao seu caso.

```
$('#dp1').blur(function(){
    //Coloque aqui o código que você precisa
});
```

Answer (score 3):

A solução para o seu problema seria algo assim:

```
$(function(){

    $('#dp1').on('blur', function(){
     alert('Sua lista!');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando dessa maneira você está disparando o evento a cada tecla digitada no elemento em foco, o correto seria usar .blur() pois o evento só seria disparado ao sair do campo ou seja ao ter uma data digitada e você apenas validaria se o campo está com uma data preenchida.

O evento onkeyup ocorre quando o usuário solta uma tecla (no teclado) uma data teria em media 8 digitos e no caso 8 disparos da função!

```
$('#dp1').blur(function(){
  var val = $('#dp1').val();
   if(val != ""){
     mascaraData(val);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

também podemos adicionar o evento onBlur diretamente no input.

```
 <input id="dp1"  onblur="mascaraData(this);" class="input-small" onkeyup="mascaraData(this);" name="data"  type="date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy"  required="required">
```